# Bit-based universe simulation

Tags: python, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

I am working with this problem (https://open.kattis.com/problems/whowantstoliveforever). As the problem states, my program has to determine if the universe lives or dies based on the input 0s and 1s.

> To determine the next value of the i-th bit, look at the current 
>   value of the bits at positions i−1 and i+1 (if they exist; otherwise 
>   assume them to be 0). If you see exactly one 1, then the next value of
>   the i-th bit is 1, otherwise it is 0. All the bits change at once, so 
>   the new values in the next state depend only on the values in the 
>   previous state. We consider the universe dead if it contains only
>   zeros.

My code works but when submitting it to Kattis.com it says ""Time Limit Exceeded" > 3.00 s". Below is my code.

```
import sys


def get_bit(bits, i):
    if 0 <= i < len(bits):
        return int(bits[i])
    else:
        return 0


def get_new_state(old_state):
    new_state = []
    for index in range(len(old_state)):
        if (get_bit(old_state, index-1) == 0 and get_bit(old_state, index+1) == 0) or (get_bit(old_state, index-1) == 1 and get_bit(old_state, index+1) == 1):
            new_state.append(0)
        elif(get_bit(old_state, index-1) == 0 and get_bit(old_state, index+1) == 1) or (get_bit(old_state, index-1) == 1 and get_bit(old_state, index+1) == 0):
            new_state.append(1)
    return new_state


def is_dead(state):
    if set(state).pop() == "1":
        return False
    elif set(state).pop() == 1:
        return False
    elif len(set(state)) == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def foresee_fate(state):
    seen = []
    while True:
        if is_dead(state):
            return False
        if state in seen:
            return True
        seen.append(state)
        state = get_new_state(state)


num_cases = int(sys.stdin.readline().strip())
for i in range(num_cases):
    cur_state = []
    case = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
    for char in case:
        cur_state.append(char)
    print("LIVES" if foresee_fate(cur_state) else "DIES")
```

What are some ways to improve the performance of my code?

Comment: Just a note, this is basically a very simple [Cellular Automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_automaton). If you want to try other stuff like this, looking into Conway's Game of Life and a Forest Fire simulator. They're very cool learning projects.

Answer (score 6):

You are representing each state of the universe as a list of bits. However, CPUs are experts at handling sequences of bits — that's what an integer is!

Given two bits, the way to find out whether exactly one of them is 1 is to use the `^` operator (XOR).

You should be able to solve this challenge using bit-shifting (`<<` and `>>` operators) and `^`.

Answer (score 3):

Testing for state repetition by `if state in seen:` is suboptimal. The number of states could grow exponentially with number of bits (and you are dealing with 200000 bits universe). Since `seen` is a list, the search time is linear, making the total time complexity quadratic with the size of the period.

Using a set instead of list would immediately improve the performance. However, I recommend to avoid huge collections whatsoever and investigate a [Tortoise and Hare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Floyd's_Tortoise_and_Hare) approach.